# Figuring out a race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am building a screen recorder, I am using ffmpeg to make the video out from frames I get from Google Chrome. I get green screen in the output video. I think there is a race condition in the threads since I am not allowed to use main thread to do the processing. here how the code look like

This function works each time I get a new frame, I suspect the functions `avpicture_fill` & `vpx_codec_get_cx_data` are being rewritten before `write_ivf_frame_header` & `WriteFile` are done.

I am thinking of creating a queue where this function push the object `pp::VideoFrame` then another thread with mutex will dequeue and do the processing below.

What is the best solution for this problem? and what is the optimal way of debugging it

```
void EncoderInstance::OnGetFrame(int32_t result, pp::VideoFrame frame) {
    if (result != PP_OK)
        return;

    const uint8_t* data = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(frame.GetDataBuffer());
    pp::Size size;
    frame.GetSize(&size);
    uint32_t buffersize = frame.GetDataBufferSize();


    if (is_recording_) {
        vpx_codec_iter_t iter = NULL;
        const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt;
        // copy the pixels into our "raw input" container.
        int bytes_filled = avpicture_fill(&pic_raw, data, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, out_width, out_height);
        if(!bytes_filled) {
            Logger::Log("Cannot fill the raw input buffer");
            return;
        }

        if(vpx_codec_encode(&codec, &raw, frame_cnt, 1, flags, VPX_DL_REALTIME))
              die_codec(&codec, "Failed to encode frame");

        while( (pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(&codec, &iter)) ) {
            switch(pkt->kind) {
                case VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT:
                    glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::write_ivf_frame_header, pkt));
                    glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::WriteFile, pkt));
                    break;
                default:break;
            }
        }

        frame_cnt++;
    }

    video_track_.RecycleFrame(frame);
    if (need_config_) {
        ConfigureTrack();
        need_config_ = false;
    } else {
        video_track_.GetFrame(
                callback_factory_.NewCallbackWithOutput(
                        &EncoderInstance::OnGetFrame));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you record the entire screen, do you get the entire frame green, or just the part that plays video?

Comment: I get the screen as it is in YUV format, but the exported video is green. The recording peroid is correct and when I do ffprob I get correct information. I think the packets are not passed correctly or the data gets overwritten before they are encoded and written to the file.

Comment: As for the race condition/overwrite you are suspecting, I would check it, using hardware watchpoints/data/memory breakpoints and see the call stack when they are hit , then I would try pausing the thread that overwrites,  to narrow down the problem.